# Security design software

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there a plug-in for Adobe Illustrator or a stand alone software for the Mac that allows you to create anti-counterfeiting/forgery designs?

I am looking for a plug-in or software that would automate designing Guilloche patterns and maybe other security enhancements. I am not trying to print these designs myself but I am also not trying to design for high security like money. I guess, my best example would be to design tickets for an event.

Comment: What do you mean by "anti-counterfeiting/forgery"?

Comment: I can't really see a way to make digital products forgery proof, so I assume you are talking about printed material like money bills or stamps. There might be some software for this (which I don't know), but if you are going to print it using conventional methods, anyone could make a copy. Money bills are forgery proof because of all sorts of physical "trickery" like holograms, tiny details, special colors, special paper, uv inks etc. Could you tell us more about the product you are making?

Comment: Most of the anti forgery patterns you see on cheques, certificates, bank notes etc. are just that, patterns. You can look up some security patterns on the web, and purchase different pattern options from various sites. Any plug-in you find is just going to use these already created patterns, not generate new, original ones.

Comment: @GoofyMonkey well not necessarily, it could generate them so they are new.

Comment: @joojaa I suppose it's possible. I've yet to see one do it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't a program that automates this make it easier to counterfeit? A forger would just need to know which program/tool that was used and put in considerably less effort to match the pattern. Just a thought...

Comment: @zeethreepio not nesseserily, computer programs can be based on unique seeds/instruction sets inserted by users. While anybody might be able to generate exact same pattern if they know the exact program, the trick is rather that the number of possible permutations of possibilities is so mindboglingly high that finding the exact one would take forever. Encryption couldnt work if this was not the case, knowing tge program that did it may be just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: I'm intrigued but i still don't quite get it. What kind of forgery are you trying to avoid? Photocopying/scanning an existing ticket, someone stealing the original pdf and print it themselves or someone recreating the design from scratch? Guilloche patterns looks cool and fine sharp lines of any kind would be harder to photocopy, but I'm not sure the design itself matters as much as the production method. If you added something special like a special kind of paper, a metallic spot color or a cut-out it would be hard to copy.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Inkscape, it's free and works on Mac/Windows/Linux. It's a vector image editor, similar to Adobe Illustrator (which is not free).

You can generate security patterns (commonly called *guilloché* patterns) with the Spirograph extension and the Interpolation extension. Both extensions are pre-installed in the software.

Examples made in Inkscape:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but it seems to me that beside the spirograph plugin for Inkscape, and the janky but viable commercial product coded in Russia called Excentro, the basics of most Guilloche patterns could be achieved in Illustrator using Blends...

[image]

I think this generates more than enough detail to perform the required task.

[image]